# I want to redirect the application to external url in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public void GoToUrl()
{
    var authorizationRequest = "https://www.google.com/";                       
    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(authorizationRequest);
}
```

I want to redirect to the user to the url `google.com` from the above method. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
>
> public void GoToUrl()
> {
>     var authorizationRequest = "https://www.google.com/";                       
>     _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(authorizationRequest);
> }
> ```
>
> I want to redirect to the user to the url google.com from the above
> method. Any help will be appreciated.

I have created a sample using your code, it will show the following error:

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'Test.Controllers.HomeController'`

After register the IHttpContextAccessor in the ConfiguraServices method (in the startup.cs file), your code works well, it will redirect to the external url. Please check your code and try to register it.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Second, as Athanasios Kataras said, you could also try to use the Controller.Redirect(String) Method, try to modify your code as below:

```
    //Try to use IActionResult, instead of `void`.
    public IActionResult GoToUrl()
    {
        var authorizationRequest = "https://www.google.com/";
        // assuming that you are in the controller.                    
        return this.Redirect(authorizationRequest);
    }
```

Finally, if above methods still not working, you could return the external url to the client side, then use the `window.location.href` property to display the external web page.

Code in the Controller:

```
    public IActionResult GoToUrl()
    {
        var authorizationRequest = "https://www.google.com/";                 
        return Json(authorizationRequest); 
    }
```

Code in the View:

```
<input type="button" id="btnredirect" class="btn btn-info" value="Redirect" />
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnredirect").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Home/GoToUrl",  
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    window.location.href = data; 
                } 
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not what I am trying to do. I dont need to redirect to url after a button click or from a controller .Just want to redirect the user to url from a void method that is in class not in controller @Zhi Lv

Answer (score 0):

Use the controller redirect method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

```
public void GoToUrl()
{
var authorizationRequest = "https://www.google.com/";    
// assuming that you are in the controller.                    
return this.Redirect(authorizationRequest);
}
```

Comment: I am getting error Redirect does not exist in current context @Athanasios Kataras

Comment: Yes, its MVC core. But, my method is in a class not in a controller @Athanasios Kataras

Comment: My bad, you need the controller redirect method, check the updated answer.

Comment: You will need to bubble up an indicator that the controller needs to redirect. This a value that the controller should return.

Comment: what if I do not want to redirect from controller @Athanasios Kataras

Comment: There is no other way. The controller will return the value to the browser, indicating that the browser needs to redirect. Check http response code 301.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras, When using `return this.Redirect ()` method, the GoToUrl method should use the 'IActionResult' key word, instead of the `void`.